# How to let AGVs notice each other?

Tags: anylogic

I have a path guided fleet of AGVs driving a loop with one loading and one unloading point. I want them to not come closer to each other then 20cms, so that there is queue. However in my simulation they seem to not notice each other. Sometimes 4 AGVs are interleaved. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AnyLogic; but their site suggests that overlaps may occur if the animation's size doesn't match the object's defined size (at least, that's said for pedestrians; but presumably you can have the same issue anywhere this animation:data mismatch occurs). https://anylogic.help/anylogic/troubleshooting/troubleshooting.html#pedestrian-library

Comment: Thank you JohnLBevan for your response but that is not the case in my model. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Here's a bit more documentation which may be useful? https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/rail-library/preventing-train-collisions.html#preventing-train-collisions https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/material-handling-library/path-guided-navigation.html

Comment: I found the mistake. It had to do with the position of the homelocation and what the AGV has to do when there is a new task